# YUP validation: compare mathematical values of fields 'a' and 'b' to field 'c'

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup

Hello I am quite new to YUP and trying to like it :)

I am able to get yup to do the basic (built-in) validation stuff, but I can't seem to figure out how to do validation that involves a bit of math.

For instance, I'm aware that you can use Yup.ref('field') and .lessThan to validate field_1 against field_2, but what if you wanted to do something like this?

if ((field_1 * field_2} < field_3) {  return an error   }

I am aware by reading the documentation that you can add custom methods (ie: addMethod) to yup, but I have failed to make this approach work so far.

Any help or a link to a solid example of how to use addMethod in this manner would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

I finally found an example I could use.  I used the '.test' object in YUP and wrote a function.  Sorry for the newbie questions.  Here is my resolution:

```
.test('test-compare a few values', 'U suck at math (this is the failure message for the test)',
   function(value) {
    let value1 = this.resolve(Yup.ref("1st_number"));
    let value2 = this.resolve(Yup.ref("2nd_number"));
    let value3 = this.resolve(Yup.ref("3rd_number"));
    if((value1 * value2) > value3)
         return false;
    else
         return true;
    }),
```

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: Yup is not defined` for this, so I will go with `this.parent.fieldName`

Comment: @Tamas Mostly people do `import * as Yup from "yup"`. Maybe that's how this code was set up.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `this.parent['sibling_form_field_id']` inside the `test` function to retrieve the values of the other form fields by id.

So you can do this:

```
YUP.string()
  .test('test-compare a few values', 'U suck at math (this is the failure message for the test)',
    function (value) { // beware, don't use arrow function here otherwise you would not the reference to `this` object
      let value1 = this.parent['1st_number']; // retrieve the value of the sibling form field with id `1st_number`
      let value2 = this.parent['2nd_number']; // retrieve the value of the sibling form field with id `2nd_number`
      let value3 = this.parent['3rd_number']; // retrieve the value of the sibling form field with id `3rd_number`
      if ((value1 * value2) > value3)
        return false;
      else
        return true;
    },
  );
```

Comment: Nice one, notice that you mustn't use arrow functions otherwise the `this` will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this pattern according to project requirements**

```
const Schema = Yup.object().shape({

  sellMinAmount: Yup. number(),

  sellMaxAmount: Yup. number(),

  btcAmount:Yup.number("please enter only no")

    .test("Is greater than sell MIn mount?",

  "sellMinTrade Validation Error",  
          
  (value,sellMinTrade) => { 

    const customError = `The sell field must be greater than 50 or more`;

    if(value < sellMinTrade?.parent.sellMinAmount) {

       return sellMinTrade.createError({message: customError });  
   
    }
    else {
       return true;
    }
  }  
});
```